# i18next not loading in file from public folder

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I am trying to load multiple translation files to react app.
So far, I've been able to seperate the files
was having issues with it trying to append the name of two different translations file -- `/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json?lng=en+es&ns=translation1+translation2)`

I have solved this but now it will not read from the public folder

my config file looks like the following

```
import i18n from 'i18next'
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend'
import Http from 'i18next-http-backend'
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next'
import BackendAdapter from 'i18next-multiload-backend-adapter'

const languages = ['en', 'es']

i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    defaultNS: 'menus',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    whitelist: languages,
    lng: 'en',

    backend: {
      backends:[
        new BackEndAdapter(null, {
          backend: new Http(null,{
            loadPath: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json?lng={{lng}}&{{ns}}`,
            addPath: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}`,
            allowMultiLoading: true
          })
        })
      ]    
    },

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false
    }
  })

export default i18n
```

package.json

```
{
   "i18next": "^19.5.1",
   "i18next-http-backend": "^1.0.15",
   "i18next-multiload-backend-adapter": "^1.0.0"
}
```

using [this](https://www.i18next.com/overview/plugins-and-utils#backends) as reference as to why multiload adapter is needed

Comment: Why do you need BackEndAdapter?

Comment: I was following the documentation and the link they told to follow
https://github.com/i18next/i18next-xhr-backend#backend-options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```js
import i18n from 'i18next';
import HttpBackend from 'i18next-http-backend';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';

const languages = ['en', 'es'];

i18n
  .use(HttpBackend)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .init({
    defaultNS: 'menus',
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    whitelist: languages,
    lng: 'en',

    backend: {
      loadPath: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json?lng={{lng}}&{{ns}}`,
      addPath: `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/locales/add/{{lng}}/{{ns}}`,
    },

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });

export default i18n;
```